# Yammer Embed Like Button: How to get number of likes

Tags: yammer

I used Yammer 'Like' action button using yammer embed for article pages in sharePoint. I believe that when user clicks on 'like' an **Open Graph** object is created in Yammer. Also, activity is posted in activity stream as "[user] **likes** [article title]".

However, I have 2 queries regarding this:

1. When different people like the same article, then how to view the **number** of likes for this article **in yammer**?
2. How to obtain the total **number** of likes to be displayed next to 'Like' button on **article page**. For ex: 2,455 people like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible in the current implementation of the Yammer Embed Like button.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Brian!